# How to Map Multiple Columns to single column in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am new to SSIS and have this below flat file and need to load into Orders table in MS SQL Server,

```
ID,Order1,Package1,Order2,Package2
1,O1,P1,O2,P2
2,O3,P3,O4,P4
3,O5,P5,O6,P6
```

I need to load above flat file values into Orders table just like bleow using SSIS,

```
ID  Order   Package
1   O1       P1
2   O2       P2
3   O3       P3
4   O4       P4
5   O5       P5
6   O6       P6
```

and I am trying to map all (O1 to O6 and P1 to P6) columns to Order and Package as show below,but i could not.

[image]

any solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

From `SSIS` solution point of view you could achieve this like below -

Once you have read your flat file you need to distribute your input row into two which could be done by `Multicast`. Then you have `Union` your multicast- ed data as one. Now in `SSIS` there is no straight forward concept of `ROW_NUMBER()` so that has to be achieved using `Script Component` as transformation.

[image]

Union All -
[image]

Script Component code (use this inside ScriptMain : UserComponent) -

```
int rowNumber = 1;
    string order = "";
    string package = "";

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if ((order != Row.Order) & (package != Row.Package))
    {
        Row.ID = rowNumber;
        rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;
    }

    order = Row.Order;
    package = Row.Package;
}
```

Reference : [link](https://jasonstrate.com/2011/01/23/31-days-of-ssis-generating-row-numbers-2331/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `unpivot` the data.

This could be done in the source query

```
SELECT [ID], [Order1] AS [Order], Package1 AS [Package] FROM <table_name>
UNION ALL
SELECT [ID], [Order2] AS [Order], Package2 AS [Package] FROM <table_name>
```

Or in SSIS a `Multi Cast` followed by a `Union All` transform should work the same.

```
[Source]---->[Multi Cast]====>[Union All]---->[Destination]
```

The setup for the `Union All` would look like

```
Output  | Input 1  | Input 2
-----------------------------
ID      | ID       | ID
Order   | Order1   | Order2
Package | Package1 | Package2
```

In your example you create a new ID, this could be done with `ROW_NUMBER` or in SSIS using a [`Script Transform`](https://jasonstrate.com/2011/01/23/31-days-of-ssis-generating-row-numbers-2331/)

Example using `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT 
   [ID] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [ID], [Priority]),
   [Order],
   [Package] 
FROM (
    SELECT [ID], 1 AS [Priority], [Order1] AS [Order], [Package1] AS [Package] 
    FROM <table_name>
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [ID], 2 AS [Priority], [Order2] AS [Order], [Package2] AS [Package] 
    FROM <table_name>
) t
```